# How to fix "Can't open file" in react-native(android) after file download with rn-fetch-blob?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using **rn-fetch-blob** to download PDF file in **react-native (android)**. File downloads successfully but when i try to open it says **"Can't open file"**.

```
RNFetchBlob.config({
    fileCache: true,
    appendExt : extension,
    addAndroidDownloads : {
        useDownloadManager: true,
        notification : true,
        path: DownloadDir + "/me_"+Math.random().toString().slice(2, 6) + '.' + extension,
        mime : 'application/pdf',
        mediaScannable : true,
    }
})
.fetch('GET',         'https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf'
          , { 'Cache-Control': 'no-store' })
        .then((res) => {
            alert('The file has saved!')
            console.log('The file saved to ', res)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' to you androidManifest.xml

Then add this to your code,

```
 const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    )
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED)
```

see, if that helps

Comment: Thanks for answering
It seems funny but actually reason was that i was using emulator and emulator did not have the application to open pdf file.